# how do i stop my div tags from overlapping the header

Tags: css, html, whitespace

Ok so i am trying to create a 3 column layout with css and html on Expression web and when i view it in a browser my left panel div column overlaps my heading div column and my right panel div column overlaps the header also.Plus theirs a lot of white space between my main content column and my right panel column. Its no white space in between the layout when its minimized but it still overlaps.please help

Comment: Please mention your code so that we can figure it out what's going wrong in there!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your specific problem is without seeing your code. I find the best way to learn CSS is by example. so, I'd suggest looking through these.

(I haven't looked to see if these are using the latest design standards)
http://layouts.ironmyers.com

Or my favorite layout.

http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail